# my ls command in terminal is showing deleted Microsoft documents

Tags: terminal, mac, command-line, bash, ms-office

ls command in the mac terminal always shows deleted Microsoft documents in the following syntax `~$[name].docx`. I tried to clear all the cache in `~/Library/Caches` and `~/LibraryLibrary/ApplicationSupport/Microsoft/Teams`. But still, that won't go out, I will attach a picture to this query.

This is always happening for Microsoft documents so I figured it is someone to deal with cache, but I don't know how to resolve this. I researched a lot, but no one answered this question on any platform.

This is kind of annoying everytime when you try to print ls and see what files are in there, it always prints almost 100 lines of output which is not even there. My bin is also empty, and I have had this problem for more than 3 months.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent. When including Terminal output in a post, please copy/paste as text and format as code, it's much easier to read that way (and also allows people with screenreaders to read it).

Answer (score 9):

These are temporary files MS Office applications create while editing files. In theory they should get removed when you quit the application, but they may remain in case of crashes and probably other issues. When they show up in `Downloads` they could also have been part of a ZIP file which somebody created while having the actual doc/xls files still open.

To remove them, quit all MS Office applications and then run

```
cd ~/Downloads
rm ./~\$*
```

Comment: you are awesome!!!!! it worked

Comment: @MathewNelson Good to hear! Are you aware of https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers ?